# How to ask for a person to come by?

Tags: expressions

For example, I'm in an office and I want to see a certain person. How do I ask at the reception to ask this person to come down?

In other words, would those sound correct?

> Can I ask for Peter, please?
>
> Would you please call for Peter?
>
> May I see Peter, please?

Comment: What is your relationship with Peter and what tone do you want to set?  "I need Peter down here right away" "Please call Peter and have him come down- I need to speak with him" "Could you please ask Peter to come down" "I need to speak with Peter if he's in." "Is Peter in, I would like to speak with him"  "I was wondering if you would call Peter and see if he'll come down to speak with me" "I'd like to speak with Peter if it's convenient" "Would Peter be available to speak with me sometime?" "Could I make an appointment to speak with Peter- unless he's available now..." etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternatives suggested in the question and in Jim's comment (*ie* “I need Peter down here right away”, “Please call Peter and have him come down – I need to speak with him”, “Could you please ask Peter to come down?”, “I need to speak with Peter if he’s in”, “Is Peter in, I would like to speak with him”, “I was wondering if you would call Peter and see if he’ll come down to speak with me”, “I’d like to speak with Peter if it’s convenient”, “Would Peter be available to speak with me sometime?”, “Could I make an appointment to speak with Peter – unless he’s available now...”) are mostly acceptable (depending, of course on circumstances that apply) but I believe the most-commonly-used approach is to tell the receptionist something like  “I'm here to meet with Peter Smith”,  “I'm here to meet with Mr. Smith”, “I have a 3:00 appointment with Peter Smith”,  “I'm John Jones, here to meet with Peter Smith”, etc.